# Pivot data base on number of values in group by, instead of a full pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to pivot a dataframe in pandas. In the example below, the pivot would be on the id column and value is the value column. But instead of a normal pivot where each of the ids would be their own column (several thousand in my real dataset), I want (3) generic id columns since each type usually only has 1-3 ids.

I tried using pivot and pivot table functions in pandas. I have also been playing around with groupby without aggregation. Is there a more straight-forward solution? Is there a term for what I am trying to achieve?

```
Starting Sample Dataset: 

type id    value
A    123   11.9
A    234   10.2
A    129   19.3
B    123   11.9
B    189   12.2
B    120   17.8
C    120   17.8
C    139   17.9
D    110   8.5

Desired Output:

type id1    id2    id3 
A    11.9   10.2   19.3  
B    11.9   12.2   17.8  
C    17.8   17.9   Nan
D    8.5    Nan    Nan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the dummy column id and then groupby using that

```
df1['aux'] = df1.groupby('type')['id'].cumcount().reset_index()[0].values
df1.pivot(index='type', columns = 'aux', values = 'value')
```

Output:

```
aux      0     1     2
type                  
A     11.9  10.2  19.3
B     11.9  12.2  17.8
C     17.8  17.9   NaN
D      8.5   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

## `cumcount`, `pivot_table` & `add_prefix`

First we can create the new id's with `cumcount` since they are in consecutive order in the groups of `type`:

Then we can pivot on this new `id` and use `add_prefix` to get your wanted column names:

```
df['id2'] = df.groupby(['type']).cumcount()+1

piv = df.pivot_table(index='type', columns='id2', values='value')\
        .add_prefix('id_')\
        .reset_index()\
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

---

```
  type  id_1  id_2  id_3
0    A  11.9  10.2  19.3
1    B  11.9  12.2  17.8
2    C  17.8  17.9   NaN
3    D   8.5   NaN   NaN
```